# Database on a Virtual Machine on an Azure Scale Set

Tags: database, azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I have to set up a database on an Virtual Machine on a Scale Set, for scalability. This database will update itself every 30 sec from an external source and it will be then used (read only) internally in Azure by other virtual machines. What I'm asking is this: How are new VMs created in a Scale set? Are they created from a **STATIC** image or are they create froma **MASTER** VM in the scale set that I can update? If a new instance of the VM is created will it have the "latest" version of the most updated VM that's already up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the new instances are created from a STATIC image. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview#why-use-virtual-machine-scale-sets).

> With scale sets, all VM instances are created from the same base OS
>   image and configuration. This approach lets you easily manage hundreds
>   of VMs without additional configuration tasks or network management.

Also, the instances in the same scale set could not have such auto-sync mechanic which enables every instance to upgrade to the latest status for your hosting application. If you want to update the scale sets, it's recommended to create vmss from a custom image as the base image. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121599/patching-and-updating-virtual-machine-scalesets).